# "Object complement" OR "participial phrase"

Tags: participle-phrases, object-complements

> In 2019 the company saw a strong uptake of its flagship *OnePlus 7- series* **regaining the top spot back after falling behind Samsung in 2018.**

Is the *bold phrase* a **participial phrase** or an **object complement?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> *In 2019 the company saw a strong uptake of its flagship OnePlus 7-*
>   *series,* [*regaining the top spot <s>back</s> after falling behind Samsung in*
>   *2018*].*

No: object complements consist of noun phrases or adjective phrases, but not clauses.

The bracketed gerund-participial clause is an adjunct, an optional item in clause structure.

Here, the adjunct has a resultative interpretation.

Incidentally, the word "back" is redundant and a comma after "series" is preferable, as shown.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97303/discussion-on-answer-by-billj-object-complement-or-participial-phrase).